# Is there a place for a command-line argument wiki format?

Tags: feature-request, markdown

What I'm talking about is a wiki syntax dedicated to explaining command lines. We can all try out best with ASCII art, bullet lists, etc, but what would be perfect would be a format that produces a presentation with roll-over highlights which pop up annotations explaining particular pieces of the command line.

Comment: What? Could you try to explain a little more what you're asking?

Comment: @Marco i think he wants somethign where each aspect of this command would be explained in a popup, for example, when hovering over: `iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --dport 12345 -j REJCET --reject-with icmp-host-unreachable` each part would be explained by a popup.

Comment: Yes (I've been away, sorry) ; that was the idea.